# Aryabhata's sine approximation : Conversion for use with interval of $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, approximation

There's this sine approximation (mentioned in title) which works over the interval $[0, \pi]$: 
$$
    \sin x \approx \frac{16x(\pi-x)} {5\pi^2-4x(\pi-x)}
$$
With little changes it can be put work over the interval $[-\pi, 0]$:
$$
    \sin x \approx \frac{-16x(-\pi-x)} {5\pi^2-4x(-\pi-x)}
$$
Approximation results as - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cvoewagqer

Is there any change to join these two formulas into one equation to work in range $[-\pi, \pi]$? If there's ... how?

Source:
P.Giblin's paper: https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/~pjgiblin/papers/sine-approx.pdf

Comment: Multiply the first one by sign(x) and then replace all the other x's by $|x|?$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Ian Thanks, this idea works as seen in plot - https://tinyurl.com/ya9fsgb2

Answer (score 1):

How about $$ \sin x = (\text{sgn}(x) 16x(\text{sgn}(x)\pi-x) / 5\pi^2-4x(\text{sgn}(x)\pi-x))$$

(*This is purely based on the formulae given.)

Comment: Thanks, this idea works (after fixing parentheses) as seen in plot - https://tinyurl.com/y9dsxpb5